# How to migrate from plain Svelte to add SvelteKit features?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I created a svelte app using Vite from the Svelte template. I have a tiny package.json and I want to start using Sveltekit. Here is the package.json

```
{
    "name": "jxb2",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.2",
        "svelte": "^3.55.1",
        "vite": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.3.2"
    }
}
```

However, the docs dont say anything about making this ugprade. Sveltekit talks about how to [create a project](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project) but says nothing about upgrading from svelte. I want to use [the routing feature](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

I can find a page about [migrating from sapper](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating) but i dont want to do that, I want to get there from Svelte

Answer (score 4):

What I ended up doing was just copy-pasting my whole project over from the svelte proj into the sveltekit proj

Took about three minutes because it's still a small job. Mostly changed `./path` to `../path` to accommodate my files now being in `/src/routes` instead of `/src/App.svelte`